# Using RestSharp in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm trying to use RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) in a Windows Phone 7 project, but I'm having an issue it seems with the Newtonsoft Json.NET library that RestSharp uses. When I'm trying to execute my code like so:

```
_restClient.ExecuteAsync<Model.Song>(restRequest, (response) =>
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { }
    else { }
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

`Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Compact, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30AD4FE6B2A6AEED'.`

`Newtonsoft.Json.Compact.dll` is copied to the Bin folder of my Windows Phone 7 application, so I'm assuming it gets deployed to the device, but somehow it won't load it. Has anyone experienced/solved something similar? Thanks.

---

As requested, an example of the JSON: `[{"type":"Song","id":60097,"title":"A Place Where You Belong","artist":{"type":"Artist","id":17,"nameWithoutThePrefix":"Bullet For My Valentine","useThePrefix":false}}]`

And the classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Song
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "artist")]
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Artist
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "nameWithoutThePrefix")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "useThePrefix")]
    public bool UsePrefix { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're not the first to get this problem. Can you post the JSON and C# classes you're trying to use?

Comment: Added to the original post, hopefully it's something that can be resolved, as `DataContractJsonSerializer` isn't really working all that well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of the `[DataMember]` attributes, they're not used by RestSharp.

Since the JSON returned is an array, you need to deserialize that to an array:

```
client.ExecuteAsync<List<Song>>(request, callback);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick either. I'm still getting the same error with `List<Song>`: `"Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Compact, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30AD4FE6B2A6AEED'."`

Could it be that since RestSharp doesn't use the `[DataMember]` attributes, that it doesn't translate from the JSON id's to my own Property names? Ie. `title->Title`, `nameWithoutThePrefix->Name`, thus causing the error?

Comment: The names are translated automatically http://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Can you try it in a non-WP7 project and tell me if it works?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: does my Class need to have the exact naming as the JSON properties, or does it use `[DataMember]` properties to link the names from the JSON to my class property names? I'll try in a non-WP7 project and will let you know if it works.

Comment: RestSharp does automatic name matching. For instance for the 'nameWithoutThePrefix' element, your property would need to be named NameWithoutThePrefix. The link I sent over early shows all the steps it goes through to match the name.

Comment: So I tried it in a Silverlight project and got an error (with the exact same code) in `RestSharp.cs` at the `GetHandler` method: `NullReferenceException` at `var semicolonIndex = contentType.indexOf(';');`. `contentType` seems to be `null` here. I also tried it in a Windows Forms application with the same code, which does seem to fill my `response.Data` property with the correct data, so I'm assuming right now it's an issue with the Silverlight/Windows Phone components of RestSharp.

Comment: We'll have to work this out either in the new Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/RestSharp or email firstnamelastname@gmail.com