# How to consume rest wcf services in wiindows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wrote rest wcf services .The below is the published path.
http://{ipaddress}/Frnetwork/incidents/help

How to consume these services in windows phone 7.
Please tell me.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use RESTSharp its really good and reasy RESTClient helper lib.. i am not sure if it works with WP7 but seems like it worth a try because a post on SO says it will work.

http://restsharp.org/

[Using RestSharp in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537035/using-restsharp-in-windows-phone-7)

Regards.